# Reordering a variable in the training and testing sets

Tags: generalized-linear-model, categorical-data

I have a training set with 80% of the data and the testing set with the remaining 20%. I am fitting a GLM where one of the predictors is categorical with 5 different values. I was taught that a categorical variable like that should be ordered so that the first level of the variable is the most common. My problem is that the most common level is different in the testing and training set, so I'm wondering what I should be doing here.

Comment: This advice sounds very strange to me.  It's not clear what the "first" level of a categorical variable is, unless it happens to be ordinal.  But if it's ordinal you don't get to decide what the first level is.

Comment: The levels are in alphabetical order. I'm trying to get them in frequency order.